# Unknown provider: $scopeProvider in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a ionic project and I am trying to call a factory method from a controller. This factory method is in a separate file.When doing so, I am getting the following error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- loginService
```

Here are my files:

services.js

```
 angular.module('starter.services', ['starter.constants'])
.factory('loginService', function($scope, $http,constants) {
 var lgurl = constants.BASE_URL+constants.User_Login;
 return {
 loginXmanager: function(username,password,deviceID,deviceType){
 /*Demo*/
  return $http.post(lgurl).then(function(response){
     users = response;
     return users;
   });
  }
 }
});
```

controllers.js

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services'])

 .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', 'loginService',function($scope, 
 $ionicModal, $timeout,loginService) {


 // Form data for the login modal
 $scope.loginData = {};

 // Create the login modal that we will use later
 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
   scope: $scope
 }).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal;
 });

 // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
  $scope.modal.hide();
 };

 // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
  $scope.modal.show();
 };


 $scope.doLogin = function() {
   console.log('Doing login');
   var usrnm = $scope.loginData.username;
   var pass = $scope.loginData.password;
   var deviceID = "1234";
   var deviceType = "any";
   console.log('username - '+usrnm);
   console.log('password - '+pass);
   if (loginService) {
    loginService.loginXmanager(usrnm,pass,deviceID,deviceType);
  }else{
    console.log("loginService error");
 }

};
}])
```

What seems to be the issue here?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $scope is only used to connect with the view...a factory doesn't do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because you cannot inject `$scope` in a factory. So, change your factory to:

```
.factory('loginService', function($http, constants) {
```

Also, in your controller, injections are not fully provided and are out of order. It should be as follows:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'loginService', '$timeout', '$ionicModal',
    function($scope, loginService, $timeout, $ionicModal) {
```

Answer (score 1):

can't use scope variables inside the factory. remove the `scope` injector from the factory

change this

```
.factory('loginService', function($scope, $http,constants) {
```

to this

```
.factory('loginService', function($http,constants) {
```

Also in the controller follow the format when injecting service as string values

change this

```
 .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', 'loginService',function($scope, 
 $ionicModal, $timeout,loginService) {
```

to this

```
 .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$ionicModal','$timeout','loginService', function($scope, 
 $ionicModal, $timeout,loginService) {
```